# Lending Club dataset "complete" with credit scoring

Tags: bank

I would like to do some data analysis on the Lending Club dataset.  The Lending Club dataset is really interesting and there are quite a few attempts to analyse it.

The data is available [here](https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action) but for those not registered with Lending Club the data is not complete.  This "partial" kind of data is the type  available for example on Kaggle.

Most importantly for me, this data does not contain the credit score (either the LC internal one or the FICO one).

The problem is that to get the "complete" dataset it is necessary to register, which prevents all people leaving outside of the US to get this data (the registration process is the same as the one for those wanting to invest and it is restricted to US residents).

I wonder if anybody is aware of a complete version of the date posted on message boards or similar?